# Google Sheets does not allow you to change the schedule for Add-on Analytics

Tags: google-sheets, analytics, google-analytics-api, spreadsheet, add-on

We have some spreadsheets with reports from Add-on analytics created by a person who no longer works with us. Because of this, we were unable to change the schedule of these reports or even uninstall the Add-on.

When we click on schedule a report, the following message appears:

*

> "Sorry, <--e-mail--> has already created a schedule for this
>   spreadsheet. To schedule reports, you must either have them disable
>   their schedule, or you can create your own copy of this Spreadsheet. "

*

However, this employee no longer has access to the spreadsheet and his e-mail has been disabled. How can I edit these reports even with this limitation?

Comment: I think [contacting G Suite support](https://gsuite.google.com/support/) would be your best option in this case.

Comment: How is this related to google analytics api?